# Unable to download file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am trying to download the file from the repeater. Following is my code:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filePath);
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
```

I am receiving the following exception:

[image]

The file is saved in the Data folder of the route folder:

[image]

How do I write the code to find the actual path?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your filepath is incorrect (./College/Graphic1.jpg), it doesn't match the path shown in the screenshot (./Data/Graphic1.jpg)

Comment: yes. That`s why i asked the question that what is the right code to get the actual path?

Comment: ? Change the CommandArgument on your LinkButton to be the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question. I changed my code to the following code:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient req = new WebClient();
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        string file = Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filePath;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.Buffer = true;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+filePath);
        byte[] data = req.DownloadData(file);
        response.BinaryWrite(data);
        response.End();
    }
```